# Characters in CSV Save File

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing this due to the fact that I am unable to get my Excel data transposed onto a separate CSV file without it formatting to multiple special characters. This macro was intended to pull everything required for an upload and save the file as a CSV so the user wouldn't need to bother.

Please see trouble code below. Portions of code are missing from post, however this is the troubled bit.

'''

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Columns.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Save as CSV to Client Upload File | Example : HBSFULDT", vbInformation, "Fuel Transfer Complete"
cFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="XXXFULDT", _
fileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
Title:="Save as FT Client Upload File")

If cFile <> False Then
uploadSheet.SaveAs Filename:=cFile
Else
MsgBox "Please Save Fuel Upload to Client XXXFULDT File", vbCritical 'If Cancel is pushed on SaveAs Screen
Exit Sub
End If
ActiveWindow.Close
```

'''

Example of Characters shown in notepad - E÷HüCä-JÜ²@5í‚Ç*Q>ÀÄ“Æªc[žiiÿž‰ûB¡j7±ÏÜ{2ñÍh²nm¶‚ˆÆ»R‹ÈÀU^7/ÅÇì%¿’rZYï @1__f› ˜q·ÃR4DáAJ¬h>€ãÚÇVßÆ¹ªZ¨9ÈÛÁàNVÞ8Ê©ÓãÑÔji){^óã-I‹"{Üv^¥P!XS)bR¹rú—K¾s(¸3Õ`cÞ0†½ÝÎß»¾7M4²©ŠôªZÆk+¿|\|z¿(Ž‹ôPúº6h_-[ž@!‚ÒØ Pk‹´­2nÏ}Ä?£LËðÂ Ýû%áÄßdºždN"m,à¥ÇžDO97*‚~§ÈÉ¸8ÀOíc|n¦Ñä

Comment: Please define "trouble". Do you receive an error? If yes, what error and on which line? If not, what do you want to accomplish versus what the code does...

Comment: The document does save as a CSV and if I open within Excel it shows the proper values in all rows, however if I upload to our system, or open in Notepad/Notepad ++ it shows a bunch of characters instead that are not recognized. No error from Excel.

Comment: All you're doing is saving your workbook with a "csv" extension: you also need to specifiy the fileformat to be CSV   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas  see the FileFormat argument.  You want to use `xlCSV` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code that says `uploadSheet.SaveAs`, doesn't specify a FileType. The default will be xls or xlsx, regardless of the filename.

eg. if you save an excel file as MyDemo.csv, it will still be a xls. Excel will figure it out when it opens the file, without complaining about the name mismatch

This code should fix it

```
'replace this line
uploadSheet.SaveAs Filename:=cFile

'with this line
uploadSheet.SaveAs Filename:=cFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV 'or 6, which means CSV format
```

For info, and other settings, check out the `SaveAs` docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas